# usage of explicit keyword for constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, explicit

I was trying to understand the usage of explicit keyword in c++ and looked at this question on SO
[What does the explicit keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162)

However, examples listed there (actually both top two answers) are not very clear regarding the usage. For example,

```
// classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String {
public:
    explicit String(int n); // allocate n bytes to the String object
    String(const char *p); // initializes object with char *p
};

String::String(int n)
{
    cout<<"Entered int section";
}

String::String(const char *p)
{
    cout<<"Entered char section";
}

int main () {

    String mystring('x');
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have declared String constructor as explicit, but lets say if I dont list it as explicit, if I call the constructor as,

```
String mystring('x');
```

OR

```
String mystring = 'x';
```

In both cases, I will enter the int section. Until and unless I specify the type of value, it defaults to int. Even if i get more specific with arguments, like declare one as int, other as double, and not use explicit with constructor name and call it this way

```
String mystring(2.5);
```

Or this way

```
String mystring = 2.5;
```

It will always default to the constructor with double as argument. So, I am having hard time understanding the real usage of explicit. Can you provide me an example where not using explicit will be a real failure?

Comment: Are you expecting `String('x')` to call `String(const char*)`? `'x'` is a `char`, not a `char` pointer. Anyway, you're only showing *explicit* constructions of a `String`, so `explicit` doesn't make a difference. Try calling a function that takes a `String` with an `int`, and it won't work, because the conversion `int` → `String` can't be made *implicitly*.

Comment: `String mystring = 'x';` [does _not_ work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79af8ce27adf8a61).

Comment: @cpplearner I am aware of that, thats why I indicated that I dont use the word explicit. In your example, you are using explicit

Comment: @Biffen can you expand your argument with an example code

Comment: @UnderDog Which argument? If you mean calling a function that takes a `String`, then see Jerry Coffin's answer.

Comment: @biffen I looked at it but I am already aware of that usage. And thats the point of my whole question, I am aware that if I declare the constructor as explicit, and then I call a constructor with argument as same type as that of the constructor that has been declared as explicit, the type of definition I do matters, but if there is no explicit, I can define it anyhow and I would always get the right behavior. I am looking for examples where not using explicit fails

Comment: @UnderDog Not using `explicit` won't *fail*, but it can give undesired behaviour.

Comment: @Biffen But Jerry coffin's examples doesnt show that undesired behavior or may be I am not understanding it correctly

Comment: @UnderDog Well, if I were to write a string class, I would *not* want it to be implicitly convertible from an `int`, because the conversion is not *obvious* (whereas that from `const char*` *is*). Does it turn the number into a string? Does it get a string from some numbered reference? I'd rather force the user to be *explicit* when they want to use that constructor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`explicit` is intended to prevent *implicit* conversions. Anytime you use something like `String(foo);`, that's an explicit conversion, so using `explicit` won't change whether it succeeds or fails.

Therefore, let's look at a scenario that does involve implicit conversion. Let's start with your `String` class:

```
class String {
public:
    explicit String(int n); // allocate n bytes to the String object
    String(const char *p); // initializes object with char *p
};
```

Then let's define a function that receives a parameter of type `String` (could also be `String const &`, but `String` will do for the moment):

```
int f(String);
```

Your constructors allow implicit conversion from `char const *`, but only explicit conversion from `int`. This means if I call:

```
f("this is a string");
```

...the compiler will generate the code to construct a String object from the string literal, and then call `f` with that `String` object.

If, however, you attempt to call:

```
f(2);
```

It will fail, because the `String` constructor that takes an `int` parameter has been marked `explicit`. That means if I want to convert an `int` to a `String`, I have to do it explicitly:

```
f(String(2));
```

If the `String(char const *);` constructor were also marked `explicit`, then you wouldn't be able to call `f("this is a string")` either--you'd have to use `f(String("this is a string"));`

Note, however, that `explicit` only controls implicit conversion from some type `foo` to the type you defined. It has no effect on implicit conversion from some other type *to* the type your `explicit` constructor takes. So, your explicit constructor that takes type `int` will still take a floating point parameter:

```
f(String(1.2))
```

...because that involves an implicit conversion from `double` to `int` followed by an explicit conversion from `int` to `String`. If you want to prohibit a conversion from `double` to `String`, you'd do it by (for example) providing an overloaded constructor that takes a `double`, but then throws:

```
String(double) { throw("Conversion from double not allowed"); }
```

Now the implicit conversion from `double` to `int` won't happen--the `double` will be passed directly to your ctor without conversion.

As to what using `explicit` accomplishes: the primary point of using `explicit` is to *prevent* code from compiling that would otherwise compile. When combined with overloading, implicit conversions can lead to some rather strange selections at times.

It's easier to demonstrate a problem with conversion operators rather than constructors (because you can do it with only one class). For example, let's consider a tiny string class fairly similar to a lot that were written before people understood as much about how problematic implicit conversions can be:

```
class Foo {
    std::string data;
public:
    Foo(char const *s) : data(s) { }
    Foo operator+(Foo const &other) { return (data + other.data).c_str(); }

    operator char const *() { return data.c_str(); }
};
```

(I've cheated by using `std::string` to store the data, but the same would be true if I did like they did and stored a `char *`, and used `new` to allocate the memory).

Now, this makes things like this work fine:

```
Foo a("a");
Foo b("b");

std::cout << a + b;
```

...and, (of course) the result is that it prints out `ab`. But what happens if the user makes a minor mistake and types `-` where they intended to type `+`?

That's where things get ugly--the code still compiles and "works" (for some definition of the word), but prints out nonsense. In a quick test on my machine, I got `-24`, but don't count on duplicating that particular result.

The problem here stems from allowing implicit conversion from `String` to `char *`. When we try to subtract the two `String` objects, the compiler tries to figure out what we meant. Since it can't subtract them directly, it looks at whether it can convert them to some type that supports subtraction--and sure enough, `char const *` supports subtraction, so it converts both our `String` objects to `char const *`, then subtracts the two pointers.

If we mark that conversion as `explicit` instead:

```
explicit operator char const *() { return data.c_str(); }
```

...the code that tries to subtract two `String` objects simply won't compile.

The same basic idea can/does apply to `explicit` constructors, but the code to demonstrate it gets longer because we generally need at least a couple of different classes involved.

Comment: I am not sure if you are correct on conversion from doubt to int. If I pass in a double value to String object, it will directly go to the constructor which expects double as argument (if there is any), irrespective of explicit.

Comment: @UnderDog: Yes and no. Yes, that's the one overload resolution will select. But, if it's marked explicit, and you're trying to use it to do an implicit conversion, then the code won't compile.

Comment: I understand that and I agree. But my question is not regarding that. I am more interested to know about the cases or an example code, where not using explicit causes a failure or an undesired behavior, because so far with the explanation that I have understood, I dont see much worth in using explicit.

Comment: @UnderDog: I've added an example.