# C++: Compilation error with explicit keyword

Tags: c++, overloading, explicit, explicit-conversion

The following code throws compilation error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Option
{
    Option() { printf("Option()\n"); };
public:
    explicit Option(const Option& other)
    {
        printf("Option(const)\n");
        *this = other;
    }

    explicit Option(Option& other)
    {
        printf("Option(non-const)\n");
        *this = other;
    }

    explicit Option(const int&)
    {
        printf("Option(value)\n");
    }
};

void foo(Option someval) {};

int main()
{
    int val = 1;
    Option x(val);
    foo(x);
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
main.cpp:31:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Option::Option(Option&)’
     foo(x);
          ^
main.cpp:5:5: note: candidate: ‘Option::Option()’
     Option() { printf("Option()\n"); };
     ^~~~~~
main.cpp:5:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp:25:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(Option)’
 void foo(Option someval)
```

The error goes away if I remove the explicit keyword from `explicit Option(const Option& other)`

Can someone explain to me what is the cause of compilation error?
Also, if there a difference between `explicit Option(const Option& other)` and `explicit Option(Option& other)`?

Comment: It is typical to see an `explicit` constructor to protect against unwanted implicit conversions, but an `explicit` copy constructor is very odd.

Comment: For the explicit keyword [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean) is a good description. In this particular case, the explicit keyword prevents copying x when you call the foo function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310944/usage-of-explicit-keyword-for-constructors) is a good discussion about when to use explicit constructors. 

The difference between the two copy ctor is with the non const version, you cannot copy const objects. In general the const version of copy constructor is enough, you don't have to specify both of them.

Comment: Inside the function `explicit Option(const Option& other);`, what is `*this = other;` supposed to call?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it calls the [implicitly-declared copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal There is none - it's implicitly deleted since there's a user defined copy constructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if you check the page I linked, there is no mention that the copy constructor prevents the generation of copy assignment operator. Also check Item 17 in Modern Effective C++ from Scott Meyers, it explain this further.

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal From _Item 17:_ "_[...] C++11 deprecates the automatic generation of copy operations for classes declaring copy operations or a destructor_". Clear enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210471/discussion-between-janos-benjamin-antal-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: Just to clarify things: it just deprecated, not reomved. It compiles with `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` with gcc 9.3 and clang 10.0.0. With clang, you need `-Weverything` beside `-Werror` to make the compilation fail

Answer (score 2):

In the call `foo(x)`, a new `Option` has to be created, which will become `someVal` during the execution of `foo`'s body. That is, `x` needs to be copied into `someVal`. The compiler essentially tries to initialize `Option someVal(x);` (trying first `Option(Option&)`, then `Option(Option const&)`), but it cannot, because you said that both of those constructors are `explicit` and should not be implicitly called. With C++17, you can explicitly insert the missing constructor call to make it work: `foo(Option(x))`. Before C++17, it is impossible to call `foo`, because the compiler will keep trying to insert calls to a constructor to `Option` but none are available for insertion.

In the language of the standard, a function call like `foo(x)` calls for the parameter `someVal` to be *copy-initialized* from `x`. Copy-initializing an object of a certain class from an object of that class or a derived class considers only the *converting constructors* of that destination class. "Converting constructor" is just a fancy name for "constructor that isn't `explicit`". The best constructor out of these is then selected by normal overload resolution. Since *none* of your constructors are not `explicit`, this always fails and `foo` is uncallable before C++17. Since C++17, when the argument is a prvalue (as in `foo(Option(x))`), the requirement to call a constructor can be sidestepped and `foo` becomes callable.

To your side question:

> Also, if there a difference between `explicit Option(const Option& other)` and `explicit Option(Option& other)`?

Of course: the first one promises it will not modify its argument and the second one doesn't. You already know that they can be defined to do different things, and overload resolution will prefer one over the other, depending on context:

```
Option x(1);
Option const y(2);
Option a(x); // calls Option(Option&) if available, which may modify x; calls Option(Option const&) if not, which shouldn't modify x
Option b(y); // must call Option(Option const&) because that promises not to modify y; cannot call Option(Option&) because it may modify y
```

Comment: In C++17 it is possible because of new copy elision rules, or something other? If something other, could you please name the feature? It was a surprise for me that it works with C++17.

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal Yes, it's copy elision.