# How parameter type conversion in C++ operator works?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, explicit-constructor

I am creating a new class VarDbl, which contains a few explicit constructors as well as a + operator:

```
class VarDbl {
    ...
    explicit VarDbl(double value, double uncertainty);
    explicit VarDbl(double value);
    explicit VarDbl(long long value) noexcept;
    explicit VarDbl(long value) noexcept : VarDbl((long long) value) {}
    explicit VarDbl(int value) noexcept : VarDbl((long long) value) {}
    ...
    VarDbl operator+(const VarDbl other) const;
    ...
};
```

Because this class is easy to copy, I use const VarDbl other instead of the reference.

I am trying to test the implementation with the following code:

```
    VarDbl v1(1, sqrt(2));
    VarDbl v = v1 + 2;
```

gcc complains on the last line as:

```
no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'VarDbl' and 'int')
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Cheng/OneDrive/Documents/Proj/VarianceArithemtic/Cpp/TestVarDbl.cpp",
    "owner": "makefile-tools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'VarDbl' and 'int')",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 185,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 185,
    "endColumn": 19
}]
```

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion, it seems that `int` should be converted to VarDbl by using the `explicit VarDbl(int value)` constructor to create a temporary copy, but it does not happen.

Why?

Comment: Remove explicit on the appropriate constructors. Explicit forbids implicit conversions.

Comment: [explicit is intended to prevent implicit conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36311158/12002570)

Answer (score 1):

`explicit` constructors are not *implicitly* invoked.  You need to remove `explicit` if you want them to be used automatically like that.